# How to program Fiddler to restrict IP range while in reverse proxy mode?

Tags: javascript, http, ip, fiddler, reverse-proxy

I've configured Fiddler as a [reverse proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp) on port 8888 (to forward to 80) using its [rules file](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp).   Now I want to restrict the IP range that can access the reverse proxy as a security measure.

Is it possible to do this using only the Fiddler rules file without needing to configure the firewall or anything external to the Fiddler programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to OnBeforeRequest.

There, you can get the client's IP address using the property `oSession["X-CLIENTIP"]`, and if you're not satisfied with the value, do something like `oSession.oRequest.FailSession(403, "Proxy access denied", "You are not permitted to use this site.");`

---

**Update by question author**

Sample script used:

```
// restrict usage to IPs and ranges
if (oSession["X-CLIENTIP"].indexOf(/*My Business, modify to your IP range>*/"0.0.0.") != 0 
    && 
    oSession["X-CLIENTIP"].indexOf(/*private*/"192.168.") != 0  
    &&
    oSession["X-CLIENTIP"].indexOf(/*localhost*/"127.0.0.") != 0 
    && 
    oSession["X-CLIENTIP"].indexOf(/*private*/"10.") != 0 
    ) {

    oSession.oRequest.FailSession(403, "Proxy access denied", "Your IP# is not permitted to use this Fiddler debugger.");

    return;
}
```

Also note that IPv6 might throw a monkey wrench into things because X-CLIENTIP can be
`192.168.100.139` or `::ffff:192.168.100.139`   At this point the programmer might consider using regex tests like this one that matches either incarnation of the IP#:

```
/^(?:\:\:ffff\:)?192\.168\..+/.test(oSession["X-CLIENTIP"])
```

Comment: That's great, it works like a charm. I've appended my actual script to your answer for future ref - it might help others.

Comment: A fast way to see what X-CLIENTIP is reporting to Fiddler is to put this statement as the first in the OnBeforeRequest function of the rules file `oSession.oRequest.FailSession(403, "Proxy access denied", oSession["X-CLIENTIP"]);` without any conditions to cause it to always fail and print the value, then hit the proxy with any web browser. Remove or comment it out when finished.  There might be a different way to see this value in Fiddler, but I haven't found it.

Comment: You can see the X-ClientIP flag, and all of the others, by right-clicking on a session and choosing Properties. (Or select one and hit ALT+ENTER).